# Row of cards not scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a row of cards that are sized so that two fit to the width of the screen then the next two appear below.

I am struggling to get the top of the `#card row` to be 10px below the `#title-row` above and to be at the bottom of the `#main-container` and scrolling if the screen isn't tall enough.

```css
#card-row {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#main-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#title-text {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "CallingAngelsPersonalUse";
  text-shadow: 4px 6px 12px #fff;
}

#date-text {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Strawberry_Whipped_Cream";
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 6px #fff;
}

  #card-title {
    font-family: "CallingAngelsPersonalUse";
    font-size: 30px;
    left: -5px;
    bottom: -20px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <div id="title-row" class="row">
    <div class="container center">
      <div class="show-on-medium-and-up hide-on-small-only">
        <p id="title-text">Scott and Viki</p>
        <p id="date-text">23rd June 2018</p>
        <a id="button" class="black waves-effect waves-light btn z-depth-3" href="mailto:who@gmail.com?subject=Wedding%20R.S.V.P"><i class="material-icons right">email</i>R.S.V.P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Agenda Card -->
  <div id="card-row" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#agenda-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="./assets/SVSunset.jpg" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Order of the day</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Map Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#map-modal').modal('open');" role="button" (click)="openChurchMap()">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="./assets/1.jpg" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Map's and Directions</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    6 more cards as above
  </div>
```

Currently, everything is where it should be but when you scroll the cards only move 10px or so. How can I fix this so its dynamic for all screens? Also the `#card-row` is hugging to the left which i cant get to center either?

Comment: Is the code in the question enough to replicate the issue? Because on a quick glance it doesn't look it

Comment: As Andy Holmes correctly stated, in order for someone to investigate scrolling behavior, they need to have the full css of the elements involved (ie card, card-image classes)

Comment: theres not much else to it, ive missed out the modals as they are irrelevant i though. this is all there is on the page, i can add the other 6 cards html but they are practically identical to the others

Comment: @Wazza you need to add whatever styling/html required to accurately replicate the issue. I looked at your snippet and cannot replicate your issue

Comment: Ive added everything, im using material css with angular. I cant see anything else? When i add  `height: 60vh;` to the  it scrolls but this wont work for all view heights?

Comment: Can you post the url to your site?

Comment: hi the site is here https://scottandviki.herokuapp.com/ and the github repo is here https://github.com/wrumble/scottandviki